# Is $\frac{n!}{\left(n/2\right)!\left(n/2\right)!}$ a natural number for $n$ even?

Tags: natural-numbers

Probably this is a easy question, but I was unable to solve it. Let $n$ be a even natural number. Is true that the following number is natural for all $n$? $$\frac{n!}{\left(n/2\right)!\left(n/2\right)!}$$

I can see, for example, that $(n/2)!$ divides $n!$, but then I can't conclude by using this arguing.

Thank you

Comment: Yes, because the symmetric group on $n$ objects contains a direct product of two copies of the symmetric group on $n/2$ objects (those fixing the first $n/2$ objects and those fixing the last $n/2$ objects).

Comment: It's a binomial coefficient, hence an integer.

Comment: Also, $k!$ divides any product of $k$ consecutive integers. (which is due $\begin{pmatrix}n\\k\end{pmatrix}$ being an integer, of course.)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, it is. Suppose that $n=2m$; then

$$\frac{n!}{(n/2)!(n/2)!}=\frac{(2m)!}{m!m!}=\binom{2m}m\;,$$

which is the number of $m$-element subsets of a set of $2m$ things. This clearly must be an integer. For more information, see the Wikipedia article on [binomial coefficients](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_coefficient).

Comment: So simple, thank you.

Comment: @Tomás: You’re welcome.

Answer (score 5):

Yes. This is just $\displaystyle {n \choose n/2}$.